# How to replace equations in a docx using python?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

[image: Screen capture of Word document]

I am using [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to search and replace specific words in a Word document. These words need to be replaced not only in text, but also in tables and equations. The problem is that the program is not changing the words that are in equations. (I've searched in the documentations of docx, but didn't find anything.)

In the figure above, the tags #RTC and #RTP are highlighted. After executing the code, all the tags were changed, with the exception of the tags in equations. This is the function that I am using:

```py
from docx import Document

def replace_string2(filename):
    doc = Document(filename)
    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        if "#RTC" in p.text:
            print('SEARCH FOUND!!')
            text = p.text.replace('#RTC', '800')
            style = p.style
            p.text = text
            p.style = style      
    # doc.save(filename)
    doc.save('test.docx')
    return 1
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample .docx file, with notes on specifically what result you're getting vs. what you expect, to make this a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I can't find how to add a .docx file to the topic. But the problem is just with the equations, so if I have, for example, a file with only an equation with the tag that I'm searching (#RTC), my program can't replace it with the value (800). On the other hand, if this tag were just a text, or if it were inside a table, it would work.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot? You can upload images of the relevant section of the document before and after processing, and embed them directly in the post.

Comment: I added the figure. So, I made a couple changes in the code but the problem still persists. I searched in the documentation of the library docx, but couldn't find anything about this...

Comment: Interesting note I discovered while fiddling with this: even Word's own search-and-replace feature (at least in my ancient 2011 version) isn't able to find the contents of equations!